# Dynamic row add/delete in Thymeleaf

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have implemented dynamic row add/delete in thymeleaf using jquery. But I am unable to capture the row values as array of json objects.

```
$(function(){      
         $('#addMore').on('click', function() {          
             var data = $("#tab_logic tr:eq(1)").clone(true).appendTo("#tab_logic");
             data.find("input").val('');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
        var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
           if(trIndex>1) {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
          } 
     });
```

The table to which dynamic row gets added/deleted is as below:-

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
<tr class="tr-header">
<label for="requestno">Sales target</label>
    <th>Team lead</th>
    <th>Sales volume</th>
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);"
        style="font-size: 18px;" id="addMore"> <span
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input  type="text" name="teamLead"  class="form-control" ></input>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input  type="text" name="salesVolume"  class="form-control" ></input>
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove'><span
            class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a>
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem in details like under which action that you can't get value and expected output.

Comment: @Chris  My problem is to get the values of these dynamic rows as an array of json objects. As the rows are dynamic, I am finding it difficult to run them in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialized forms inputs using the serialize() function. This will return a query string that then can be converted to JSON object using JSON.stringify(). So, my recommendation, would be to add everything inside a form and then serialize it.

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
<tr class="tr-header">
<label for="requestno">Sales target</label>
    <th>Team lead</th>
    <th>Sales volume</th>
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);"
        style="font-size: 18px;" id="addMore"> <span
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></th>
</tr>
<form id="myForm>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input  type="text" name="teamLead"  class="form-control" ></input>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input  type="text" name="salesVolume"  class="form-control" ></input>
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove'><span
            class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a>
    </td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
$(function(){      
     $('#addMore').on('click', function() {
         // Add the row to your form, not the table.          
         var data = $("#tab_logic tr:eq(1)").clone(true).appendTo("#myForm");
         data.find("input").val('');
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
       if(trIndex>1) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
      } 
 });

 // Method that will generate the JSON object.
 function toJSON() {
     var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
     console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
 }
```